# How to insert to database user with default value?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to register user and I have 3 fields in form; login, password and confirm_password. In database I have column `login`, `password` and `role`. So I want to insert database user which have default role `User`. This oode below show me error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'role' doesn't have a default value`. How can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add/modify the Role column with your SQL Client, chances are you have not defined a default value to it, and the column is a "Not Null" one meaning you can't insert a row if this column is empty.

Another option is to have something like that with your create function :

```
$user = User::create([
    'login' => $data['login'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    'role' => "User"
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create users only with role "User" you can add this line when you create user;

```
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'login' => $data['login'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'role'=>"User"
        ]);
        $user->assignRole('role');
        return $user;
}
```

Or you can use Observer:

```
class UserObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the "User" created event.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function creating(User $user)
    {
        if (is_null($user->role)) {
            $user->role= "User";
            $user->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller Logic:

```
$user = User::create([
        'login' => $request->login,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password)]);
```

Model Logic if you want to insert default value

```
class User extends Model
{
    
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->role='user';
        });
    }
}
```